# Handling long text in width-constrained layouts

Tags: mobile, layout, mobile-application, page-layout

I'm working on an application in which there are occasionally single-word strings that need to be represented in a box that isn't wide enough to contain the word unbroken:

[image]

The example above is in German, but this happens with rare English words as well.

Does anyone have advice on how to deal with these kinds of texts? I could shrink the font or try to hyphenate the word, but neither of those approaches is bulletproof. We tried moving the little icon in the lower left but it looks awful anywhere but the lower left hand corner (for contextual reasons).

Any advice or thoughts others can offer would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an **ellipsis (…)**

Ellipses are used to shorten words when the text gets too long. *This can also be called truncation*.

Even though most operating systems truncate texts in the middle as seen below:

[image],

**What may be applicable in your case is truncating at the end.**

Here are 2 examples from Medium *(left)* and Google Hotels *(right)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! These examples are super helpful reference points. I'll leave this open in case others have helpful thoughts, but this may be the simplest solution...